# Django multiple Admin Model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I Wanna use 2 Admin apps such as :

- django-admin-sortable
- django-import-export

Is there a way to use both in Admin Form ?
I mean my code is using SortableAdmin:

```
class RuleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = '__all__'


class RuleAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'section', 'subsection',)
    readonly_fields = ('author', 'date_posted')
    fields = ('title', 'section', 'subsection', 'content', 'author', 'date_posted')
    form = RuleAdminForm
```

with `.register(Rule, RuleAdmin)`

If I want to use import-export I need to create this :

```
class RuleResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Rule


class RuleResourceAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = RuleResource
```

But I can't register with `.register(Rule, RuleResourceAdmin)` since Rule is already registered

Is there a way to have both options ? Using sortable admin to sort my rules, and the possibility to import CSV etc.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using of proxy model.

```
    class RuleProxyModel(Rule):

          class Meta:
                proxy = True


admin.site.register(RuleProxyModel,RuleResourceAdmin)
```

[How to use proxy model](https://micropyramid.com/blog/overriding-django-model-behaviour-with-proxy-model/)